# How to get the row under the cursor for a QTableWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Is there a way to get the row number under the mouse pointer? I want to remove a row without knowing the row number, but with just the cursor position.

EDIT:

[image]

In This image you can add projects for the Asset Library. 
When the Delete Bin is clicked the row should be removed. The best way would be to query the ROW number under the Mouse pointer while the bin is clicked. Where the row number is parsed to the removeRow function. 
I dont know how to make use of the QPointer for that. And cellEntered needs row/col values which wont stay the same when new rows are added or remvoved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of approaches that could solve this problem. Some can involve cursor location, and others can get into the table events and signals. A problem with using the QCursor to solve this, is if someone triggers the button with the keyboard as opposed to the mouse click, which means the cursor position might not reflect the correct row.

Since you are already using the high-level `QTableWidget`, then here is a really simple way to do it:

```
from functools import partial

class Table(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Table, self).__init__()

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(3, 2, self)

        for row in xrange(3):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Item %d" % row)
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, item)

            button = QtGui.QPushButton("X", self.table)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 1, button)

            button.clicked.connect(partial(self._buttonItemClicked, item))

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

    def _buttonItemClicked(self, item):
        print "Button clicked at row", item.row()
```

In this example, we just bake the item of the first column into the clicked callback, so when you click them they have a reference for asking the row number. The approach would be different for lower level model/view.

Comment: Thanks. What if [you don't have any QTableWidgetItem in the row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633311/get-the-index-of-a-qtablewidget-row-knowing-its-elements)?

Comment: @Jérôme, looks like you already have your answer via your edit... to make sure you add a `QTableWidgetItem` that can track the row.

Comment: I also got a better answer using QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex.

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you need is to use the signal `cellEntered` and the slot `removeRow` (if you're using `QTableWidget`). See the docs [here](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html?highlight=qtablewidget#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.cellEntered) for **PySide** and [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#cellEntered) for **PyQt**. You may also need to look up this topic in the **Qt** docs [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellEntered).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the removal is supposed to happen e.g. on a mouse click, all views have the [indexAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) method,
that will map any cursor/mouse location to a model index:

```
modelIndex = myView.indexAt(cursorLocation) # where cursorLocation is a QPoint instance
```

With that, it's straightforward to make changes to the model.

Alternatively, similar to doru's answer, views also implement the `entered` signal and others, notifying you of mouse actions on a certain modelindex:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#signals

Comment: in my  project i used table widget can you please tell me how can we know  the where the cursor is blinking in table widget?