# Get the index of a QTableWidget row knowing its elements

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

[I'm using PyQt4, but I think this Qt4 issue is not Python specific.]

I have a `QTableWidget`. In each row, the first column holds a button. When clicked, the row is removed.

To remove the row, I use `removeRow(int row)` method, which takes as argument the index of the row. When connecting the signal, I can't know the index of the row because it might change in the meantime (for instance if the first row is removed, all row indexes are changed).

[The accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649625/how-to-get-the-row-under-the-cursor-for-a-qtablewidget) suggests to pass the callback an instance of a QTableWidgetItem in the line, then get the row number from this item at deletion time.

This would be nice, except none of the elements of the row is a `QTableWidgetItem`. The elements are the button itself and a few ComboBoxes.

I can't figure out a way around this.

Can I somehow fit one of my elements into a QTableWidgetItem? Should I add a QTableWidgetItem in some sort of hidden column?

Our current implementation uses `indexAt(QtGui.qApp.focusWidget())` (see other answer to question mentioned above), which looks like a sorry workaround to me.

If I replace the button with a checkable QTableWidgetItem like this

```
rm_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
rm_item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                 QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

I have a QTableWidgetItem I can use to get back to the row index. But I don't know how to catch a "checked" or "clicked" event from it like I do with the button. All I found is the `itemClicked` signal of `QTableWidget`, but then I'd have to filter all the other widgets out.

There has to be something obvious I'm missing.

**Edit**

From what I read [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/7971), I could add both a QTableWidgetItem with setItem and a Button widget with setCellWidget to the same cell. This doesn't seem so natural to me, but apparently it works (can't test right now).

I guess I'll do that. Add the Button, plus a dummy QTableWidgetItem on the same cell to pass as a reference to the row.

Is this how it is meant to be?

**Edit 2**

Or maybe `QTableWidget` is not the proper Widget and I should be using a `Layout`, as suggested [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56547-QTableWidget-cellwidget-selection).

Comment: This is not a python answer, but I think my C++ answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29177041/616644) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using a layout rather than a table is possibly the most "correct" answer, but that may come with it's own difficulties, as seen in my answer to this question:

- [How to delete widgets from gridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213853/pyside-how-to-delete-widgets-from-gridlayout/21222826#21222826)

If you want to continue using a table, a somewhat cleaner solution than adding dummy items would be to use a [persistent model index](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpersistentmodelindex.html):

```
            button = QtGui.QPushButton(text, self.table)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, column, button)
            index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(
                self.table.model().index(row, column))
            button.clicked.connect(
                lambda *args, index=index: self.handleButton(index))

    def handleButton(self, index):
        print('button clicked:', index.row())
        if index.isValid():
            self.table.removeRow(index.row())
```

Comment: Thanks again, @ekhumoro. Works a treat. I just used `button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handleButton(index))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
def set_button(self, row, col):
    # create a push button 
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Remove row')
    # connect to action
    btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_row)
    # set in cell 
    self.setCellWidget(row, col, btn)


def remove_row(self):
    # find what is clicked 
    clicked = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
    # position 
    idx = self.indexAt(clicked.pos())
    # remove this row
    self.removeRow(idx.row())
```

Comment: This is what we do already, but I feel weird about using cursor location here. When connecting the signal, we know the row elements, so it is a bit twisted to lose this information deliberately and then seek cursor position afterwards. Besides, if the button is clicked from the keyboard, the method fails (see [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649625/how-to-get-the-row-under-the-cursor-for-a-qtablewidget)).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.   
AFAIK you are right: with `table.itemclicked` you have to check the state of the checkboxes. I didn't find another way, by now.   
NB: keyboard interaction with the buttons is working correctly with me.

Comment: I suppose if you click from the keyboard and the mouse pointer is on another line, `indexAt(QtGui.qApp.focusWidget())` will return the index of the other line. Anyway, see the edits I made to the question. I think I have an acceptable workaround (use both a QTableWidgetItem and setCellItem in the same cell) and an answer which is that I shouldn't be using a QTableWidget in the first place but a QLayout.